# Calculate limit with or without the use of l'Hospital's rule or series expansions

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\left(\frac{\cos^2x}{x}-\frac{e^x}{\sin x}\right)$$

One can easily calculate this limit by using series expansions for the functions appearing inside the round brackets, yielding $-1$.
My question is: can anyone give another proof of this result without the use of either l'Hospital's rule or series expansions?

Comment: If you combine the difference into a single fraction, then using l'Hopital's rule twice will lead to the answer. However, I agree with Peter Foreman that using series expansions is probably the most straightforward way.

Comment: Yes. Is there a more clever way of calculating it...?

Answer (score 4):

Your limit can be found using the series expansions and hence asymptotics of each function near $x=0$.
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\frac{\cos^2{(x)}}{x}-\frac{e^x}{\sin{(x)}}\right)
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\frac{\sin{(x)}\cos^2{(x)}-xe^x}{x\sin{(x)}}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\frac{\sin{(x)}(1+\cos{(2x)})-2xe^x}{2x\sin{(x)}}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\frac{(x+o(x^2))(1+1+o(x))-2x(1+x+o(x))}{2x(x+o(x))}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\frac{2x-2x-2x^2+o(x^2)}{2x^2+o(x^2)}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\frac{-2x^2+o(x^2)}{2x^2+o(x^2)}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(-1+o(1)\right)\\
&=-1\\
\end{align}$$

**Edit**: As stated by Greg Martin one can instead use the first terms of the Laurent series expansion of each fraction about zero giving
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\frac{\cos^2{(x)}}{x}-\frac{e^x}{\sin{(x)}}\right)
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\frac{1+o(x)}{x}-\frac{1+x+o(x)}{x+o(x)}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\frac1x-\frac1x+\frac{o(x)}{x}-\frac{x+o(x)}{x+o(x)}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(-1+o(1)\right)\\
&=-1\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, this is how i calculated the limit (-1).

Comment: I think it's more natural to simply calculate the Laurent series of the two fractions individually, yielding $\frac1x + O(|x|)$ and $\frac1x+1+O(|x|)$ respectively.

Comment: Nowhere did you say in the original question that you calculated the limit this way. You did not even describe how you calculated it.

Comment: I guess you will have to take my word on that. Can you calculate it otherwise...?

Answer (score 2):

$$=\left(\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1-\sin^2x}x-\dfrac1{\sin x}\right)-\lim\dfrac{e^x-1}{\sin x}$$

The second limit converges to $1$

For first, either use $\sin x\approx x$ for $x\to0$

Or use [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion) to find $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac1x-\dfrac1{\sin x}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Just some trigonometry and a bit of asymptotic calculus:

- $\dfrac{\cos^2x}x=\dfrac{1+\cos 2x}{2x}=\dfrac{2-\cfrac{4x^2}2+o(x^2)}{2x}=\dfrac1x-x+o(x);$
- $\dfrac{\mathrm e^x}{\sin x}\sim_0\dfrac{\mathrm e^x}{x}=\dfrac{1+x+\dfrac{x^2}2+o(x^2)}x=\dfrac1x+1+\dfrac x2+o(x) $,

Therefore
$$\frac{\cos^2x}x-\dfrac{\mathrm e^x}{\sin x}=\dfrac1x-x+o(x)-\Bigl(\dfrac1x+1+\dfrac x2+o(x)\Bigr)=-1-\frac{3x}2+o(x)$$

Comment: Oops! It's getting late here… Fortunately, that doesn't change the limit. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\cos^2x}{x}-\dfrac{e^x}{\sin x}
&=\dfrac{1-\sin^2x}{x}-\dfrac{e^x}{x+O(x^3)}\\
&=\dfrac{1-(x+O(x^3))^2}{x}-\dfrac{1+x+O(x^2)}{x+O(x^3)}\\
&=\dfrac{1-x^2+O(x^3)}{x}-\dfrac{1+x+O(x^2)}{x}(1+O(x^2))\\
&=\dfrac{1-x^2+O(x^3)-(1+x+O(x^2)(1+O(x^2))}{x}\\
&=\dfrac{1-x^2+O(x^3)-(1+x+O(x^2)}{x}\\
&=\dfrac{-x-x^2+O(x^3)}{x}\\
&=-1-x+O(x^2)\\
&\to -1\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: This is no different from using l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Of course it is. Using the first few terms of Taylor series generally work and does not depend on assumptions about numerator and denominator of the fraction.

Comment: I don't agree. You are still computing derivatives and the number of terms that you need to use in Taylor's expansion just tells you how many times you would have to apply l'Hopital's rule. If the limit exists, the assumptions turn out to be the same.